# Что представляет собой понятие сервер в веб - разработке?

Tags: javascript, json, сервер, websocket, backend

Пытаюсь понять и найти информацию что подразумевается под понятием "**сервер**" или "**EBS**" в веб - разработке, если не путаю, то это еще называют **back-end**. 
Т.е некоторые элементы созданные на *html*, с стилем заданным на *css* и с поведением заданным кодом написанном на *javascript* представляют собой собственно веб страницу. 
Допустим кнопка поставить лайк, после клика по ней "прибавляет" к текущему значению + 1 (глобально). В теории я примерно понимаю что в коде этой кнопки указано, что после обработки события (например *onclick*) она отправляет запрос на "сервер" в котором хранится текущее "реальное" значение, после чего сервер обратно отправляет ответ в виде данного "реального" значения (или это значение уже суммируется на сервере). Логично что у "клиента" и "сервера" есть функция которая "слушает", но я не нашел никаких примерных реализаций подобных функций. Хотелось бы узнать как именно конкретно происходит это "общение" между клиентской стороной и *back-end*? 
Существуют ли на русском языке ресурсы или книги в которых можно ознакомиться с данной темой? 
А также понять такие термины например как: *JSON*, *Websocket*? 
Существуют ли (и какие?) базовые вещи которые обязательно должны присутствовать даже в самом примитивном "back-end"?

Comment: Вопросы понятны. Вот как ответить кратко

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заданные вами вопросы очень обширные и вопрос таким образом [не подходит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) под формат данного сайта, потому что для ответа нужно писать статью. Также думаю, что все эти вопросы можно найти в интернете без труда по первым же ссылкам в поисковике. Вот краткий ответ:

Веб-страница может работать без сервера. За исключением того, что она откуда-то должна загружаться в браузер посетителя. Например страница может загружаться локально с ПК.

Часто веб-странице нужен свой компьютер для вычислений, хранения данных или других задач, которые не возможно реализовать в браузере. Ну или просто чтобы с него загружаться в браузер.

Сервер - это компьютер с выходом в сеть. Он может быть крошечным, например Raspberry Pi в шкафу в спальне. Или большой железной коробкой в стойке в датацентре. Зависит от задач.

В вашем примере с лайком сервер необходим для того, чтобы где-то сохранить информацию об этом лайке. Без этого другие пользователи веб-страницы не смогут увидеть ваш лайк. Для этой задачи хватит очень простого компьютера, который запомнит этот лайк и сможет по запросу сказать сколько всего лайков. Обычно для таких простых задач используется не сервер, а арендуется его кусочек, это называется хостинг или виртуальный сервер.

Общение веб-страницы и сервера происходит явно или через фоновой обмен данными. Явно - это например когда отправляется форма, и вся страница перезагружается. Фоново - это когда отправляется [AJAX-запрос](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX). В браузере для обоих способов есть стандартные функции. Например метод [fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch) в JavaScript может отправлять данные на сервер и принимать ответ.

Сервер (какой-то компьютер в сети) подключен к интернету и у него есть свой адрес. На этом компьютере запущена программа, называемая обычно HTTP-сервер, которая принимает и отправляет данные по сети. Когда вы с веб-страницы отправляете данные на адрес компьютера-сервера, то программа-HTTP-сервер реагирует на этот запрос и отправляет что-то в ответ. Примеры таких программ: Apache, Nginx, Node.js.

Более подробно про общение клиентской и серверной части вы можете прочесть например по запросу [http протокол](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP).

JSON и Websocket описать кратко не возможно. Это не простые понятия.
[JSON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) - это текстовый формат данных. Служит для удобного их представления и чтения.
[Websocket](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) - это протокол обмена данными. Имеет некоторые преимущества по сравнению с обычными фоновыми запросами-ответами. Чтобы понять их назначение и преимущества, нужен хотя бы минимальный опыт веб-разработки.

Нет таких вещей, которые обязательно должны присутствовать на бэкэнде. В одном случае будут одни вещи, в другом другие. Зависит от задач. Например это может быть устройство, подключенное к сети, просто говорящее текущее время. А веб-страница будет его отображать. Для этого на устройстве может не быть никаких программ.

На русском языке почитать про общение браузера и сервера на JavaScript можно в [этом цикле статей](https://learn.javascript.ru/network).